# Add UIView above NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I need to put a UIView between Status bar and Navigation bar in Swift.

I have seen many answers but none of the seems to work.

Here is my code

```
    let newView = UIView()
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "header"
    newView.addSubview(label)
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(newView)

    let rootVC: HomeVC = UIStoryboard(.Home).instantiateViewController()
    navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
    self.window?.rootViewController = self.navController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forgot to set the frame of view and label, do like

```
let newView = UIView()
    newView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height, width: view.frame.size.width, height: self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height)
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    let label = UILabel()
    label.frame = newView.bounds
    label.text = "header"
    newView.addSubview(label)
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(newView)
```

you get OP as

[image]

**Option 2**

as per your required

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let newView = UIView()
    newView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 30)
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    let label = UILabel()
    label.frame = newView.bounds
    label.text = "header"
    newView.addSubview(label)
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(newView)

    let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: newView.frame.size.height + newView.frame.origin.y, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height  )
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Anbu,
I want navigation bar also along with the newView. I tried you code but not working. I need navigation bar below the newView. I can give you an example I need like this http://bestapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/myspace-mobile-app-for-iphone.jpg

Comment: @ParthDhorda - give the moment I will update the answer

Comment: Sure @Anbu.karthik, and Thanks for helping

Comment: It worked but the height of the navigation bar is too small https://drive.google.com/file/d/1esTC7MM4JzKpMiefoieb1bRiMHByRlGN/view

Comment: @ParthDhorda- are you seen i tried in viewdidapper , show your tried code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169991/discussion-between-parth-dhorda-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: Hello @Anbu. I am testing in real device today and The navigation bar shift's to top and goes underneath the View which I have added in keyWindow