# How to show view in statusbar in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to show view in statusbar which should be visible to my all View Controller

**Example:** I need to show "No Internet Connection" in status bar and it will hide after we get connectivity of internet?

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076016/add-uiview-above-navigationbar/50076118#50076118) it will help you

Comment: Thanks for Answer, But It will not work for me because 
1, I need to show in over status bar
2, I need to show in all View Controller :'(

Comment: You need to create custom UIView which comes from top when no internet connection, which hides the status bar and when you got the internet connection just remove that custom view

Comment: But If I add view on status bar it works but if I redirect to another view the my view go behind the statusbar

Comment: No you need to bring custom view to window.... then it will work like charm

Comment: create this custom view in App Delegate class

Comment: Thank you all for helping me. @LinusGeffarth solution solved my issue. 
:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172514/discussion-between-ios-lifee-and-sarabjit-singh).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a view directly to the status bar:

```
// get the status bar
let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBarWindow") as? UIWindow

// create a subview & add it to the status bar
let subview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 20, height: 10))
subview.backgroundColor = .red
statusBar?.addSubview(subview)
statusBar?.bringSubview(toFront: subview)
```

If you declare the `statusBar` and the `noNetworkConnectionView` globally, you can access it from anywhere to show or hide it dynamically.

Result:

[image: result]

---

<sub>Disclaimer: I am not sure whether Apple will approve apps that modify the status bar in this way.</sub>

Comment: I used it for promo sceens but this doesn't work in iOS 13 anymore :(

Answer (score 1):

- Create a view

  ```
  let statusView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 40))
  statusView.tag = 1101 //used to get view whenever required
  statusView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
   //set other properties
  ```
- Show view on window

  ```
  //show on window, will be visible in all view controller
  UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.addSubview(statusView)
  UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.bringSubview(toFront: statusView)
  ```
- Hide View

  ```
  //to hide that view
  UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.viewWithTag(1101)?.removeFromSuperview()
  ```